malloc() returns a pointer to a wrong memory section
I have a simulator of a custom-designed CPU, that has the memory mapped as follows:
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 16384K  /* KiB */
    RAM (rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 512K    /* KiB */
}

From what I've tested, everything in the CPU works as expected, apart from malloc() (and similar memory allocation functions). The malloc function will return a pointer to the FLASH memory (i.e. not respecting the RAM origin).
This is the test code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern uint32_t _sidata; /* Start of .data in FLASH */
extern uint32_t _sdata;  /* Start of .data in RAM */
extern uint32_t _edata;  /* End of .data in RAM */

extern uint32_t _sbss;  /* Start of .bss in RAM */
extern uint32_t _ebss;  /* End of .bss in RAM */

void initialize_memory(void) {
    // Copy initialized variables from FLASH to RAM (.data section)
    uint32_t *src = &_sidata;
    uint32_t *dest = &_sdata;

    while (dest < &_edata) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }

    // Zero-initialize the .bss section in RAM
    dest = &_sbss;

    while (dest < &_ebss) {
        *dest++ = 0;
    }
}


int main(void){

    initialize_memory();

    int *ptr1 = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    __asm__("nop");               // just for locating this line in assembly
    __asm__("lui t0, 0x80000");   // Destination address
    __asm__("mv t1, a5");         
    __asm__("sw t1, 0(t0)");      // Storing the returned value
    __asm__("nop");
}

The __asm__ part is used for my evaluation - I can see the output of 0x80000000 and it is 8. The malloc is returning a number 8. -> that is not correct, at least it should be 0x20000008 to point into RAM.
This is the risc-v assembly part (.lss) from where I found out the register I wanted to inspect (a5 in this case):
000000bc <main>:
  bc:   fe010113            addi    sp,sp,-32
  c0:   00112e23            sw  ra,28(sp)
  c4:   00812c23            sw  s0,24(sp)
  c8:   02010413            addi    s0,sp,32
  cc:   f4dff0ef            jal 18 <initialize_memory>
  d0:   01000513            li  a0,16
  d4:   038000ef            jal 10c <malloc>
  d8:   00050793            mv  a5,a0
  dc:   fef42623            sw  a5,-20(s0)
  e0:   00000013            nop
  e4:   800002b7            lui t0,0x80000
  e8:   00078313            mv  t1,a5
  ec:   0062a023            sw  t1,0(t0) # 80000000 <_estack+0x5ff80004>
  f0:   00000013            nop
  f4:   00000793            li  a5,0
  f8:   00078513            mv  a0,a5
  fc:   01c12083            lw  ra,28(sp)
 100:   01812403            lw  s0,24(sp)
 104:   02010113            addi    sp,sp,32
 108:   00008067            ret

To see if the malloc is actually doing something, I've tested this code. The result of the second malloc is 0x20:
...
    int *ptr1 = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    __asm__("nop");
    __asm__("lui t0, 0x80000");
    __asm__("mv t1, a5");
    __asm__("sw t1, 0(t0)"); 
    __asm__("nop");

    int *ptr2 = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    __asm__("nop");
    __asm__("lui t0, 0x80000");
    __asm__("mv t1, a5");
    __asm__("sw t1, 0(t0)"); 
    __asm__("nop");
}

Linker script:
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    *(.*data*)
    
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  /* } AT> FLASH */
  /* } >FLASH AT>RAM */
 
 _sibss = LOADADDR(.bss);
  

  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    _sbss = .; 
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  /* } >RAM */
  /* } >RAM */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
        . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( __heap_start__ = . );
    . = . + 0x1000;
    PROVIDE ( __heap_end__ = . );
  } >RAM

The question is, why the output of the malloc is not respecting the origin of the RAM, on the other hand - how do I even know if that returned number is correct in the first place - wouldn't it "collide" with the data preloaded from FLASH?
Toolchain used: xpack-riscv-none-elf-gcc-14.2.0-2

I think malloc uses brk or sbrk to carve out more memory.  Are they doing what you want?

@TomKarzes I'm not sure how to properly test that.

What's the output of printf("%p", ptr1) instead ?

@Mike There is no proper terminal in my simulator (yet) to use printf on. The ptr1, as seen in register a5 has a value 8. Inside a5 is the returned value from malloc in this case, which is the pointer we are looking for.

What happens if you allocate memory through mmap() targeting an address in RAM ?

@Mike Since this is a "bare metal" program, without RTOS or linux, I'm not sure if I can use mmap; fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory

You have to figure out what symbol your libc implementation use for heap start. For example, avr-libc uses __heap_start (no underscores at the end). If you have no sources for libc, try nm /path/to/your/libc.a | grep heap or ask likner to generate map file.
